# $\phi \in L^\infty(\mu),\epsilon > 0$ $\implies $there is $M \in \Omega$ s.t. $0<\mu(M)<\infty$ and $|\phi(x)|\geq||\phi||_\infty-\epsilon$ on $M$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

I'm reading the Conway book about Functional Analysis and in one of the proofs (Theorem 1.5, Chapter II) he uses a result from measure theory which I don't manage to prove by myself:

Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $\phi \in L^\infty(\mu)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $M \in \Omega$ s.t. $0 < \mu(M) < \infty$ and $|\phi(x)| \geq ||\phi||_\infty - \epsilon$ on $M$.

I would be happy to get some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S=\{x\in\Omega: \phi(x)>\|\phi\|_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$ is of zero measure, then it contradicts the definition of essential supremum. The $M$ can be taken as $S\cap I_{n}$ for some $I_{n}$ where $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}I_{n}=\Omega$, $\{I_{n}\}$ is an increasing sequence of finite measure sets.